# Why isn't the force modelled which confines excess charge to remain inside a conductor?

Tags: electrostatics

Excess charge placed on a conductor distributes itself on the surface of a conductor. But why isn't the force which confines the charge to remain there, modelled in some way?

Comment: It is modelled in some way: by Maxwell's equations in fact! Have a look at http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node58.html for a good discussion of this.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* an electrostatic force, and it is actually the force by which atom cores of the materials *drag* electrons back to the material. In terms of potential, one could think as if atom cores make a potential well, which is so deep that electrons cannot escape it without huge energy provided from the outside.